# How to create specific Generic type class?

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a Generic Type class `ExtendedMap` that only accept `Strings`

I tried following code but it is giving me error:

> The method put(K, V) of type ExtendedMap must override or implement
>   a supertype method

```
    class ExtendedMap<K, V> extends HashMap<String, String> {

    private Map<K, Collection<V>> map = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void put(K key, V value) {
        if (map.get(key) == null)
            map.put(key, new ArrayList<V>());

        map.get(key).add(value);
    }

}
```

As suggested in answer  I have updated the code but now it is not compiling

Comment: You are declaring that `ExtendedMap` is a subclass of `HashMap<String, String>`, meaning its keys and values are strings. But you're then trying to override `put` so that its keys are values are of type K and V. That's just type incorrect. Also, you're trying to change the return type, which isn't allowed (unless the return type is covariant).

Comment: It looks like you are trying to mix inheritance with composition. You probably don't want to be extending `HashMap` at all; but rather extending something like `AbstractMap<Strimg, Collection<String>>`. But you still have to override the methods in a type-correct way.

Comment: Your class shouldn't both *be* a `HashMap` and *contain* a `HashMap`. Choose one.

Comment: @AndyTurner--If you could please update your answer, i understand this clearly now.

Comment: Seems you want a [`MultiValuedMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html) such as `ArrayListValuedHashMap<String,String>` (Commons Collections) or a [`Multimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) such as `ArrayListMultimap<String,String>` (Guava).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy: omit the type variables.

```
class ExtendedMap extends HashMap<String, String>
```

The warning you're getting isn't one mandated by the language spec; I guess it is just your IDE trying to make sure you've typed what you mean. But since there are no classes which extend `String`, there is no value in the type variables: omit them, and use `String` directly.

Comment: Thanks Andy but now It is not compiling , I have updated my full code please share your knowledge...:(

Answer (score 0):

The `ExtendedMap` class expects parameters of some type that extends `String` class. But since `String` is a `final` class, there is no such class that extends it.

Hence the warning.

As Andy said, omitting the type variables should get rid of the warning.

Comment: Yes, I checked that but now it is not compiling, please check my updated question